# How to get equal value from two different array using Lodash

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose, lodash

I have two JSON array objects below. I want to get matching stdname of stdcontinfo JSON value and add it to the stdJson respective JSON.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

```
var stdJson = [{
        "_id": ObjectId("5923ed1f610be38692e88e4d"),
        "stdname": "Bala",
        "fathername": "Kannappan",
        "mark1": 78.0,
        "mark2": 70.0,
        "mark3": 98.0,
        "mark4": 88.0,
        "mark5": 100.0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5923ed99610be38692e88e4e"),
        "stdname": "vetri",
        "fathername": "R",
        "mark1": 38.0,
        "mark2": 40.0,
        "mark3": 48.0,
        "mark4": 28.0,
        "mark5": 50.0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5923edf6610be38692e88e4f"),
        "stdname": "kumba",
        "fathername": "K",
        "mark1": 68.0,
        "mark2": 60.0,
        "mark3": 68.0,
        "mark4": 88.0,
        "mark5": 35.0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5923ee1a610be38692e88e50"),
        "stdname": "Jagadesh",
        "fathername": "P",
        "mark1": 100.0,
        "mark2": 90.0,
        "mark3": 89.0,
        "mark4": 100.0,
        "mark5": 95.0
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("5923ee6b610be38692e88e51"),
        "stdname": "Dayakar",
        "fathername": "R",
        "mark1": 70.0,
        "mark2": 80.0,
        "mark3": 69.0,
        "mark4": 60.0,
        "mark5": 55.0
    }
]

var stdcontinfo = [{
        "_id": ObjectId("592437891a87641edc58547e"),
        "stdname": "dev1",
        "email": "dev1@gmail.com",
        "phnum": 6545645645.0,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5924ffe6837e5d2224f42e00"),
        "stdname": "Bala",
        "email": "Bala@gmail.com",
        "phnum": 9965148632.0,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("592500371e469423a4f65306"),
        "stdname": "kumba",
        "email": "kumba@gmail.com",
        "phnum": 9962651490.0,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("59250085f02d4c0face17820"),
        "stdname": "vetri",
        "email": "vetri@gmail.com",
        "phnum": 9962651490.0,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("592500c6c6a6af1d6c7c3fa5"),
        "stdname": "Jagadesh",
        "email": "Jagadesh@gmail.com",
        "phnum": 1234567890,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: My expected output:
var stdJson = [{
        "stdname": "Bala",
        "fathername": "Kannappan",
        "mark1": 78.0,
        "mark2": 70.0,
        "mark3": 98.0,
        "mark4": 88.0,
        "mark5": 100.0,
        "email": "Bala@gmail.com",
        "phnum": 9965148632,
    },
    {
        "stdname": "vetri",
        "fathername": "R",
        "mark1": 38.0,
        "mark2": 40.0,
        "mark3": 48.0,
        "mark4": 28.0,
        "mark5": 50.0,
        "email": "vetri@gmail.com",
        "phnum": 9962651490,
    }
    .
    .
    .
]

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need Lodash here just use simple JS:

```
stdJson.forEach(itemA=>{
    let resItem = stdcontinfo.find(itemB=>itemA.stdname === itemB.stdname);
    if(resItem){
        itemA.email = resItem.email;
        itemA.phnum = resItem.phnum;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you can use one of the intersect functions. Not tested, but will be something like:

```
var arrayOfSameObjects = _.intersectionBy(stdcontinfo, stdJson, 'stdname');
```

And after finding the same objects you can add it to `stdJson`:

```
var stdJson = stdJson.concat(arrayOfSameObjects);
```

References:

https://lodash.com/docs/#intersectionBy

https://lodash.com/docs/#intersectionWith